# Finding records between date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to find records whose start and end date range over a particular date. Date is random and :start_date and :end_date are attributes of the prices entity.

```
date = Time.now
record_i_want = Price.where(date => :start_date .. :end_date)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do

```
Price.where(:date => start_date..end_date)
```

This will result in the following `SQL`( for start and end dates - '2014-03-27', '2014-03-28')

```
SELECT `prices`.* FROM `prices` WHERE (`prices`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-03-27' AND '2014-03-28')
```

**EDIT:**
Realized that this is the query you are looking for. Thanks, Coenwulf for pointing it out

```
Price.where(['start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', date, date])
```

Comment: This is a great tip. Didn't know that. Awesome.

Comment: This looks like it's the opposite of what the OP requests. It would be perfect if date were the field in the table, but it appears based on the text in the post that there are start_date and end_date fields in the table. So this code doesn't solve the posted problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want to select rows where your date is greater than the start_date and less than the end_date. You can specify the appropriate SQL where clause parameterized in your call to where like so:

```
Price.where([":date >= start_date AND :date <= end_date", {date: Date.today})
```

That will give you all the prices that match. If you know you'll get only one you can get it by calling first.

```
Price.where([":date >= start_date AND :date <= end_date", {date: Date.today}).first
```

Make any appropriate adjustment to the >= and <= if you want to exclude the start_date and/or the end_date from the results. If for example the Price is valid starting on the start_date but isn't valid through the end_date you can change the clause to:

```
":date >= start_date AND :date < end_date"
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
def get_record_by_date(date)
  Price.where([start_date.to_i < date.to_i] && [end_date.to_i > date.to_i])
end
```